# Ignoring files in a parallel folder in a git repository

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a git repository with two folders say A and B. I would like to put a .gitignore file in each folder so that when I am working in A files in B are ignored and while I am working in B files in A are ignored. Is this possible? A .gitignore file in A with the line ../B or ../B/* etc does not work.

Comment: This sounds like it would be better addressed just by using two different branches.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't possible, no.  The best solution is to use directory suffixes to your commands when doing something like that.  EG, when sitting in A to ignore B:

```
git status .
```

or

```
git status /path/to/A
```

Note that most `git` commands accept this, including `git commit`.  So instead of `git commit -a` to commit everything, just do a `git commit /path/to/A`.